# MySQLi count where one column is the same and another column is different

Tags: php, mysqli, count

I have a table which stores visitor information to certain websites and it is laid out like this:

```
ip_address   |   website_ref   |   page_visited  

123.123.12          abc               index.php
123.123.12          abc               anotherpage.php
123.123.12          efg               index.php
987.987.98          abc               index.php
```

I am trying to get the script to count any IP addresses which have the same `Website_Ref` and only visited a single page of the website.

In the example above, the system for `abc` should count `987.987.98` but not `123.123.12` because `123.123.12` visited more than a single page.

How would I code my MySQLi query to count only these results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
select * from table_name group by ip_address, website_ref having count(*) = 1
```

Comment: I've added this in to my script but I am not getting any results?

Comment: Did you replace table_name with the name of the a real table? @Snappysites

Comment: Yes, sorry my fault, was a PHP error rather than the query. It seems to work so far, I will test it out a little and if it works, will mark your answer as correct. Thank you for your help!